# How do I configure <Create> to ignore location.search parameters?

Tags: react-admin

It seems like any location.search parameters are automatically sent up in the POST API call made by `<Create>`.

How do I disable this functionality?

Context: I have a third party app that is redirecting to our react-admin page and there is no control over some GET params.